# Stored procedures with ef 6 and code first

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, parameters, ef-code-first

I am quite new to EF and MVC. But I have managed to create scaffolded pages with MCV5 and views.
I understand there is difference in concept between webforms and EF. But is it possible for me to execute a stored procedure that is created in SSMS.
I want the ability of have a webpage with two text boxes that take in the two in parameters the stored procedure requires, both of the parameters being strings and then display the result in a webgrid.
Is this doable with EF code first and MVC?

The code for my stored procedure is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_FindRoutes]

@DepCity nvarchar(max),
@ArvCity nvarchar(max)

AS

-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT dbo.Airlines.AirlineName, dbo.Routes.DepCity, dbo.Routes.ArvCity, dbo.Routes.FlightNr, dbo.AirlineRoutes.Fare, dbo.AirlineRoutes.AircraftAllocated
FROM  dbo.Routes INNER JOIN
         dbo.AirlineRoutes ON dbo.Routes.RouteId = dbo.AirlineRoutes.RouteId INNER JOIN
         dbo.Airlines ON dbo.AirlineRoutes.AirlineId = dbo.Airlines.AirlineId
         WHERE dbo.Routes.DepCity  LIKE @DepCity AND dbo.Routes.ArvCity LIKE @ArvCity;
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your `SP` is like this (Just a simple version of your `SP`).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_FindRoutes]  
    @DepCity string
    AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT dbo.Airlines.AirlineName, dbo.Routes.DepCity, dbo.Routes.ArvCity
    FROM dbo.Routes
    WHERE dbo.Routes.DepCity= @DepCity
    END
```

You have to create an object that has the same property names as the results returned by the stored procedure.It's like this.

```
    public class RouteForAirline
        {
            public string AirlineName { get; set; }

            public string DepCity { get; set; }

            public string ArvCity { get; set; }

        }
```

Then call your `SP` as shown below.

**Note :** You can put this on the `class file` if you can access the `DatabaseContext()`.

```
 using(var context = new DatabaseContext())
        {
         var depCityParameter = new SqlParameter("@DepCity", "colombo");
         var arvCityParameter = new SqlParameter("@ArvCity", "matara");

         var results = context.Database.SqlQuery<RouteForAirline>("sp_FindRoutes @DepCity, @ArvCity",depCityParameter,arvCityParameter).ToList();
        }
```

You can read more about this using below mentioned links.

[**Code First Insert/Update/Delete Stored Procedures**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn468673.aspx)

[**Stored Procedures with Multiple Result Sets**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj691402.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, The sp call is about what I also figured out, but how would the code be if I had to pass it both parameters.

Comment: And the sp call itself, where is placed? Is it in the same class file or in my dbcontext file?

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to instead of hard coding the parameters, that this can be done at runtime via a mvc page with two text boxes for the parameters?

Comment: You can pass those text boxses values as a parameter to the controller no ? After that assign those values to it like this : `var depCityParameter = new SqlParameter("@DepCity", depCity);`. i.e. `depCity` is the text box value.